# Swift 3 iOS10 import external framework SCLAlertView

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, uialertview, ios10

I am having awful problems all day trying to import SCLAlertView framework into my iOS 10 project. It is found here: https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift

I have tried everything. Copy and pasted the files into the project, added the .framework file as a framework, but I constantly get the error: No such module 'SCLAlertView'

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffX2M.png)

Comment: SCLAlertView might not be supported for Swift 3.0. Are you using pods?

Comment: There are are some commits about it being updated for Swift 3.0. I am not using pods.

Comment: I don't think it is updated? Still I found around 300 errors after creating project in Xcode 8.0 swift 3 version and installing by pods

Answer (score 2):

2 steps you need to do before using the framework

1- after installing the pod , you need to open the project from now on using the .workspace file (it will be in the same path of your project directory)

2- open the .workspace project and build your project

it will work i tried it now using swift 3.0